# Inserting Colon Between PHP Function Output

Tags: php, user-defined-functions

I have the following PHP function:

```
protected function getFieldRow($label, $value, $encode = true)
{
    if (empty($value))
    {
        return '';
    }

    return FoxHtmlElem::create()->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('dt')->classes('field-title')->text(JFilterInput::getInstance()->clean($label)))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('dd')->classes('field-content')->html($encode ? nl2br(FoxHtmlEncoder::encode(JFilterInput::getInstance()->clean($value))) : $value))->render();
}
```

Which outputs to a list of:

```
<dt class="field-title">Label</dt><dd class="field-content">Value</dd>
<dt class="field-title">Label</dt><dd class="field-content">Value</dd>
<dt class="field-title">Label</dt><dd class="field-content">Value</dd>
```

How can I change the function to add a Colon "**:**" in plain text within the output like so:

```
<dt class="field-title">Label : </dt><dd class="field-content">Value</dd>
<dt class="field-title">Label : </dt><dd class="field-content">Value</dd>
<dt class="field-title">Label : </dt><dd class="field-content">Value</dd>
```

Comment: HTML doesn't allow a colon there

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have edited the question to reflect an "allowed HTML" scenario, to which Valency has already supplied the answer to.

Comment: @chiappa Hope it worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add it in  alongside the Label like:

```
<dt class="field-title">Label :</dt>
```

You can do this by concatenating ':' with label;

```
$label .= " : ";
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you were to place a colon there, it WOULD appear but outside of the rules and styling of the description list.

I assume you would want it within the label tag like so:

```
protected function getFieldRow($label, $value, $encode = true)
{
    if (empty($value))
    {
        return '';
    }

    return FoxHtmlElem::create()
        ->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('dt')->classes('field-title')->text(JFilterInput::getInstance()->clean("{$label}:")))
        ->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('dd')->classes('field-content')->html($encode ? nl2br(FoxHtmlEncoder::encode(JFilterInput::getInstance()->clean($value))) : $value))
        ->render();
}
```

If you do want it the way you originally asked though, I'd guess at this being the solution (although google doesn't know what classes you are using and so neither do I so I cannot test it)

```
protected function getFieldRow($label, $value, $encode = true)
{
    if (empty($value))
    {
        return '';
    }

    return FoxHtmlElem::create()
        ->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('dt')->classes('field-title')->text(JFilterInput::getInstance()->clean($label)))
        ->append(":")
        ->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('dd')->classes('field-content')->html($encode ? nl2br(FoxHtmlEncoder::encode(JFilterInput::getInstance()->clean($value))) : $value))
        ->render();
}
```